# Как правильно наложить анимацию на кнопку

Tags: java, javafx

Мне нужно сделать анимацию, чтобы она проигрывалась при наведении на кнопку. Я кое-что написал, но выглядит кривовато. Скрины ниже.

Вот как выглядит, до того как я прикрепил графику, методом `setGraphic`, к кнопке. 
[image: loginButton]

Вот как выглядит после этого кода и наводке курсором на элемент

```
Rectangle rc = new Rectangle(0, 0, 84, 35);

rc.setFill(Color.web("56c2e1"));
ft = new FillTransition();
ft.setToValue(Color.web("3F9DB8"));
ft.setShape(rc);
ft.setDuration(new Duration(500));

loginButton.setGraphic(rc);
```

[image: loginButton]

Так вот суть вопроса в чем, можно ли квадрат как-то на фоне поставить?

Уточнение: мне нужно сделать так, чтобы цвет элемента переливался в другой, когда на него наводят курсором. А `FillTransition` привязать к `Node` нельзя. Так что пришлось сделать так, как написано выше. Переливка работает как надо, но как поставить на фон, не понятно.

Пример: http://www.demo.amitjakhu.com/login-form/

Comment: в смысле при наведении сдвигается или что?

Comment: У вас это крест рисунком или как?

Comment: @Herrgott нет, сдвигается сразу, как добавляю графику к кнопке

Comment: @АлексейШиманский забыл уточнить, это я нарисовал, курсор не скринится

Comment: @jessez так в итоге, я лично не понимаю уже что нужно?)) вам нужно, чтобы при наведении надпись "войти" сменялась плавно на крестик и другой бэкграунд? или этот самый крестик тупо рядом с надписью расположить? Что-то я потерялся

Comment: @jessez вы не такое имели в виду http://i.stack.imgur.com/RI3Nc.gif ??

Comment: @АлексейШиманский извините, что не ответил сразу, занят был. Мне нужно что бы цвет кнопочки переливался в другой, но без Rectangle этого сделать нельзя. Что бы квадрат этот был на фоне надписи "Войти". Вот пример на подобной форме http://www.demo.amitjakhu.com/login-form/

Comment: @jessez ну если нужно только цвет поменять, то сделайте  OnMouseEnter/OnMouseExit и меняйте цвет либо `new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), new KeyValue(rc.fillProperty(), Color.web("3f9db8")))` на темный и `new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), new KeyValue(rc.fillProperty(), Color.web("56c2e1")))` обратно на светлый

Comment: @АлексейШиманский но как же мне сделать так, что бы этот квадрат был на фоне надписи Войти? Получается так, что квадрат этот расширяет кнопку, а нужно что бы он был на фоне

Answer (score 1):

Хотел сделать более громоздкий способ, но не буду. Попробую написать способ через `css`.

**Примечание:** вообще при работе со стилями и `css` обычно все стили пишутся в отдельном файле, а затем подключается этот файл со стилями и работается непосредственно с селекторами. Примерно так:

```html
Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
scene.getStylesheets().addAll(this.getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();
```

Допустим крестик у вас картинкой и лежит эта картинка вместе с классом в одной папке (хотя конечно лучше в отдельную папку с ресурсами положить)

Поэтому строка с его путем будет допустим

```
String declineImage = getClass().getResource("decline.png").toExternalForm();
```

У кнопки устанавливаем стили:

```
btn.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url('" + image + "'); -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat; -fx-background-position: 8px 4px;");
```

где указываем картинку в бэкраунде, позицию и пр. Это обычный `css`

А при событии мыши OnMouseEnter/OnMouseExit  делаем прозрачным прямоугольник:

```
    btn.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            new Timeline(
                    new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0), new KeyValue(rc.opacityProperty(), 1)),
                    new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0.5), new KeyValue(rc.opacityProperty(), 0))
            ).play();
        }
    });

    btn.setOnMouseExited(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            new Timeline(
                    new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0), new KeyValue(rc.opacityProperty(), 0)),
                    new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0.5), new KeyValue(rc.opacityProperty(), 1))
            ).play();
        }
    });
```

Способ установки картинки в бэкграунд не через `css`:

```html
// new Image(url)
Image image = new Image(CurrentClass.class.getResource("/path/to/package/bg.jpg"));
// new BackgroundSize(width, height, widthAsPercentage, heightAsPercentage, contain, cover)
BackgroundSize backgroundSize = new BackgroundSize(100, 100, true, true, true, false);
// new BackgroundImage(image, repeatX, repeatY, position, size)
BackgroundImage backgroundImage = new BackgroundImage(image, BackgroundRepeat.REPEAT, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.CENTER, backgroundSize);
// new Background(images...)
Background background = new Background(backgroundImage);
```

Можете его адаптировать под себя.